# Enter key doing nothing on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input below a slider that shows the value of the slider. When the slider is moved, the input shows a currency formatted figure. I also allow the user to enter a figure and the slider adjusts accordingly.

All works perfectly other than the `enter` key cannot be used to activate the manual field changes.

The following HTML shows the input sitting under a slider like this:

```
<table class="transaction-calculations">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="invoice-slider invoice">
                <input type="range" name="avg_tran_slider" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-range form-control" id="avg_tran_slider" min="0" max="50000" value="150"><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="invoice-slider">
                <input type="text" id="avg_tran" class="slider-calculator-figure" value="$150.00"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I format its content with JS like this:

```
/** select input contents when activated **/
jQuery("#avg_tran").focus(function() {
    jQuery(this).select();
});

/** set slider position from manually entered value **/
jQuery("#avg_tran").blur(function() {

    monthly_invoice_value = jQuery(this).val();
    monthly_invoice_value = parseFloat(monthly_invoice_value.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ''));

    if(isNaN(monthly_invoice_value)) {
        jQuery("#avg_tran").val("$0.00");
        jQuery("#avg_tran_slider").val(0);
    } else {

        if(monthly_invoice_value > 50000) {
            jQuery("#avg_tran").val("$50,000.00");
            jQuery("#avg_tran_slider").val(50000);          
        } else {
            jQuery("#avg_tran").val(formatMoney(monthly_invoice_value));
            jQuery("#avg_tran_slider").val(monthly_invoice_value);
        }
        calculateCosts();
    }
});

/** set input value from slider change **/
jQuery("#avg_tran_slider").on("change mousemove", function() {
    monthly_invoice_value = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#avg_tran").val(formatMoney(monthly_invoice_value));
    calculateCosts();
});
```

Everything works perfectly other than you cannot hit `enter` when changing the field value manually as it will not "de-focus" the field and activate `blur` code.

What am I missing (apart from a few marbles now!). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `enter` key on your input if you want to execute some code.

```
jQuery("#avg_tran").keypress(function(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

    // 13 = key code of enter
    if (code == 13) {
        // Do something. Probably trigger the blur event in your case
        jQuery("#avg_tran").blur();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try It :

```
jQuery("#avg_tran").keypress(function(event) {
        var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

        // 13 = key code of enter
        if (code == 13) {
            // Do something. Probably trigger the blur event in your case
            jQuery('#avg_tran_slider').val(jQuery("#avg_tran").val());
            jQuery("#avg_tran").blur();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This looks like a copy-paste of Magus answer (with a minor addition), so I recommend you delete it to not get down votes.